# Image Upload In Google Drive

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api

I am building a web app in which I want to accept logo and some images from users.
Currently, I am storing it inside my server/images folder but my concern is scalability in the future. So I want to ask that is there any way to save all the images in my google drive account programmatically using python and only save the image URL in the database.
The web app is being built on the flask.
Or please suggest any good service

Answer (score 1):

There are many places to store images but firebase is free and is easy to use in python.

1. you can use [pyrebase](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4/tree/master/pyrebase) wrapper for [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). where you can store image delete image and get url
2. Use google drive api, here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEbL_TT9cHg) for it. or go to the google drive api [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).
3. [qwiklab](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/1075?parent=catalog) can is also available to store data.

if you want i can show you a working example of pyrebase and flask